# GCP: Can Cloud Scheduler call an endpoint for an internal Cloud Run service?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-scheduler

Just curious. I discovered documentation and did not find a simple way (without LB) to do that.

I have cloud scheduler (SC) and 2 cloud run instances (CR1, CR2).
SC calls CR1. CR2 calls CR1 as well.
I would like to keep both CR as internal/auth protected.
But:

1. If I make CR1 internal, then SC can not access CR1.
2. If I make CR1 auth protected, then CR2 can not access CR1 without code changes for CR2 that do [authentication](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/authenticating/service-to-service#acquire-token). There are 2 more projects/environments where SC and CR1 does not exist, so I do not want to write a code only for that low environment.

Comment: Looks like they updated to allow Cloud Scheduler https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed. For now only [PubSub, Eventarc and Workflow have automatic internal access](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/securing/ingress). So the Cloud Scheduler can't.

But there is a trick: you can ask Cloud Scheduler to publish a message in a PubSub topic and then create a subscription that will be able to call your ingress internal service.

Comment: It's already allowed according to the doc

Comment: 1 year later, the features have evolved!